# docker: non-root user can not write to $HOME in container

Tags: linux, docker, root

I really tried many things but still couldn't figure out how to write to $HOME inside a docker container as regular user.

Here are my commands:

```
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  docker system prune -a
WARNING! This will remove:
  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all images without at least one container associated to them
  - all build cache

Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Images:
untagged: ubuntu:18.04
untagged: ubuntu@sha256:152dc042452c496007f07ca9127571cb9c29697f42acbfad72324b2bb2e43c98
deleted: sha256:7b9813341b61d4d2475cb114919a096e51860d011d35920a1819fdd6d68c2815
deleted: sha256:9a9cbb35888dac6db6e8a5e28c57a3a7e66c40c9e35532b219452db22a8a1d6f
deleted: sha256:358db9589ef1488e86e368e3a63252ec73faf80d45e523f3c3e70ddca7462e7f
deleted: sha256:3f5a16f2d6ddbe73db188e82ea4f27b92eadd5b5d8ab6d16eb7f5aee77a59e6f
deleted: sha256:0e6f6686e47679f84b7b26673fce7ba90031fdd83974eba7d278723cf3c684da
deleted: sha256:f9a80a55f492e823bf5d51f1bd5f87ea3eed1cb31788686aa99a2fb61a27af6a
deleted: sha256:548a79621a426b4eb077c926eabac5a8620c454fb230640253e1b44dc7dd7562

Total reclaimed space: 63.55MB
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG UID
ARG GID
ARG USER


#We will build as our regular user, not as root
RUN addgroup --gid $GID $USER && adduser --uid $UID --gid $GID --disabled-password --gecos '' $USER && chown $USER:$USER /home/stulluk && ls -la /home && echo "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && ls -laR /home

RUN ls -laR /home

#WORKDIR /build
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  cat dockerbuild.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker build --build-arg UID=$(id -u) --build-arg GID=$(id -g) --build-arg USER=$USER -t nonroot-docker .
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  ./dockerbuild.sh 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  105.5kB
Step 1/6 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
18.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
7c457f213c76: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:152dc042452c496007f07ca9127571cb9c29697f42acbfad72324b2bb2e43c98
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:18.04
 ---> f9a80a55f492
Step 2/6 : ARG UID
 ---> Running in f7aa375c5e1e
Removing intermediate container f7aa375c5e1e
 ---> f9beb06727b4
Step 3/6 : ARG GID
 ---> Running in 711008a24dd8
Removing intermediate container 711008a24dd8
 ---> 214d88eb670f
Step 4/6 : ARG USER
 ---> Running in 9f2d13d66051
Removing intermediate container 9f2d13d66051
 ---> ccecf6354f23
Step 5/6 : RUN addgroup --gid $GID $USER && adduser --uid $UID --gid $GID --disabled-password --gecos '' $USER && chown $USER:$USER /home/stulluk && ls -la /home && echo "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && ls -laR /home
 ---> Running in 45ab17bbd184
Adding group `stulluk' (GID 1000) ...
Done.
Adding user `stulluk' ...
Adding new user `stulluk' (1000) with group `stulluk' ...
Creating home directory `/home/stulluk' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root    4096 Aug 19 22:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root    4096 Aug 19 22:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 stulluk stulluk 4096 Aug 19 22:06 stulluk
/home:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root    4096 Aug 19 22:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root    4096 Aug 19 22:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 stulluk stulluk 4096 Aug 19 22:06 stulluk

/home/stulluk:
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 stulluk stulluk 4096 Aug 19 22:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root    4096 Aug 19 22:06 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 stulluk stulluk  220 Aug 19 22:06 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 stulluk stulluk 3771 Aug 19 22:06 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 stulluk stulluk  807 Aug 19 22:06 .profile
Removing intermediate container 45ab17bbd184
 ---> 289168fa7f92
Step 6/6 : RUN ls -laR /home
 ---> Running in 07ff3c7cc6ab
/home:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 19 22:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 19 22:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 19 22:06 stulluk

/home/stulluk:
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 19 22:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 19 22:06 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  220 Aug 19 22:06 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3771 Aug 19 22:06 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  807 Aug 19 22:06 .profile
Removing intermediate container 07ff3c7cc6ab
 ---> 6f0a37b5315d
Successfully built 6f0a37b5315d
Successfully tagged nonroot-docker:latest
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  cat entercontainer.sh 
#/usr/bin/env bash

# run as current user
docker run --rm -it -v ${TOPDIR}:${TOPDIR}\
    --user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
    --volume="/etc/group:/etc/group:ro" \
    --volume="/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro" \
    --volume="/etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:ro" \
    --volume="/home/stulluk/.ssh:/home/stulluk/.ssh:ro" \
    nonroot-docker:latest \
    /bin/bash 
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  ./entercontainer.sh 
stulluk@c8c0fa1e42bd:/$ pwd
/
stulluk@c8c0fa1e42bd:/$ cd ~
stulluk@c8c0fa1e42bd:~$ ls -la ../
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 19 22:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 19 22:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 19 22:06 stulluk
stulluk@c8c0fa1e42bd:~$ 
stulluk@c8c0fa1e42bd:~$ touch file
touch: cannot touch 'file': Permission denied
stulluk@c8c0fa1e42bd:~$  
stulluk@c8c0fa1e42bd:~$ 
stulluk@c8c0fa1e42bd:~$ exit
exit
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  id
uid=1000(stulluk) gid=1000(stulluk) groups=1000(stulluk),4(adm),5(tty),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),122(lpadmin),134(lxd),135(sambashare),137(docker),143(vboxusers)
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $ 
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  docker --version
Docker version 20.10.25, build 20.10.25-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $
```

Why this doesn't work and how can I make it work?

Note: I don't want to bind mount my host's $HOME directory to the container. This is unacceptible solution because I don't want to write to my host.

Comment: A Docker container is a wrapper around a single process with a temporary filesystem.  What is the actual main process supposed to be (usually not an interactive shell where work will be lost as soon as the container exits)?  If I told you that "home directory" didn't have any special meaning and you could use any directory you wanted within the container, would that help you move forward?

Comment: Well it kinda helps ! I haven't thought that way to be honest. I will try mounting the $HOME of the container to some custom directory on the host and have a try. The purpose of this container is to build a yocto-like linux image for an embedded system, where "repo" tool is being used. And that repo tool needs to create its config inside a directory in $home for the initial cloning the codebase. i.e /hone/stulluk/.repoconfig . And this directory should be writeable. This is the purpose.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. It can be a bug of your particular docker version.

Comment: @Philippe what is your docker version and can you please share your commands ? In addition, my kernel is "6.2.14-060214-generic" , and could it be due to host kernel ?

Comment: I ran exactly the same commands as you and get correct /home/stulluk behavior (not owned by root). My docker version : `Docker version 24.0.5, build ced0996`

Comment: @Philippe thank you so much for your kindness & support. The issue is resolved as you will see below. I hope I can find time to report this in either docker.io or ubuntu launchpad.

Comment: If you still have the environment with bug, can you do a small test ? which is put `USER stulluk` towards the end of Dockerfile, build and run to see if you have the problem.

Comment: @Philippe sorry for late reply. I don't know what is going on, but here is what happened. I have another ubuntu 22.04 laptop, I wasn't using it for a long time. To reproduce the issue, I turned it on, and did sudo apt upgrade. This has pulled new version of docker.io. And then, I copied exactly same Dockerfile , dockerbuild.sh and entercontainer.sh from my PC to the laptop. And tried to reproduce the issue, but it all just worked fine: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/5CXjcfuP  Please also notice that, some files in $HOME ( such as .bashrc or .profile ) are still owned by stulluk , not root.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Philippe, this issue turned out to be a **bug** in the **docker.io** version that is shipped with my distro (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) which is:

```
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  docker --version
Docker version 20.10.25, build 20.10.25-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
```

I decided to give a try to **docker-ce** as suggested [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-22-04).

And then, my $HOME is perfectly writable:

```
stulluk ~ $  uname -a
Linux u22 6.2.14-060214-generic #202305010032 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon May  1 01:32:48 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
stulluk ~ $  cd docker-nonroot-test/
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  docker system prune -a
WARNING! This will remove:
  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all images without at least one container associated to them
  - all build cache

Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Images:
untagged: nonroot-docker:latest
deleted: sha256:7063344d638669d45e39318f4e4772f9f1f263e85075850c90a4917efa45ac25

Deleted build cache objects:
nuzsp9hhgd2eqgk5eta3ynrh5
8oalmweynxb5cjkrvuk93s4l6
c3esegyfdhi7ko621sqe4vgj9
swm9rskhc5fly9sbbiwhsrex3
o56163axrm6igux12k6clpkvh

Total reclaimed space: 398.3kB
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG UID
ARG GID
ARG USER


#We will build as our regular user, not as root
RUN addgroup --gid $GID $USER && adduser --uid $UID --gid $GID --disabled-password --gecos '' $USER && chown $USER:$USER /home/stulluk && ls -la /home && echo "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && ls -laR /home

RUN ls -laR /home

#WORKDIR /build
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  cat dockerbuild.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker build --build-arg UID=$(id -u) --build-arg GID=$(id -g) --build-arg USER=$USER -t nonroot-docker .
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  cat entercontainer.sh 
#/usr/bin/env bash

# run as current user
docker run --rm -it -v ${TOPDIR}:${TOPDIR}\
    --user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
    --volume="/etc/group:/etc/group:ro" \
    --volume="/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro" \
    --volume="/etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:ro" \
    --volume="/home/stulluk/.ssh:/home/stulluk/.ssh:ro" \
    nonroot-docker:latest \
    /bin/bash 
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  ./dockerbuild.sh 
[+] Building 6.4s (8/8) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                    docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                          0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 393B                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                             0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04                                                                                                                                               2.2s
 => [auth] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04@sha256:152dc042452c496007f07ca9127571cb9c29697f42acbfad72324b2bb2e43c98                                                                                         2.9s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04@sha256:152dc042452c496007f07ca9127571cb9c29697f42acbfad72324b2bb2e43c98                                                                                         0.0s
 => => sha256:152dc042452c496007f07ca9127571cb9c29697f42acbfad72324b2bb2e43c98 1.33kB / 1.33kB                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => sha256:dca176c9663a7ba4c1f0e710986f5a25e672842963d95b960191e2d9f7185ebe 424B / 424B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => sha256:f9a80a55f492e823bf5d51f1bd5f87ea3eed1cb31788686aa99a2fb61a27af6a 2.30kB / 2.30kB                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => sha256:7c457f213c7634afb95a0fb2410a74b7b5bc0ba527033362c240c7a11bef4331 25.69MB / 25.69MB                                                                                                              2.3s
 => => extracting sha256:7c457f213c7634afb95a0fb2410a74b7b5bc0ba527033362c240c7a11bef4331                                                                                                                     0.4s
 => [2/3] RUN addgroup --gid 1000 stulluk && adduser --uid 1000 --gid 1000 --disabled-password --gecos '' stulluk && chown stulluk:stulluk /home/stulluk && ls -la /home && echo "stulluk ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD  0.5s
 => [3/3] RUN ls -laR /home                                                                                                                                                                                   0.4s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                        0.1s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                       0.1s 
 => => writing image sha256:cf19a12061940f6e6f38dbc804f90d5634323600f8374c4e8f00b80c24924cfe                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/nonroot-docker                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  ./entercontainer.sh                                                                                                                                                        
stulluk@99c477bbf0ba:/$ cd ~                                                                                                                                                                                       
stulluk@99c477bbf0ba:~$ ll
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 1 stulluk stulluk 4096 Aug 20 21:59 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root    4096 Aug 20 21:58 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 stulluk stulluk  220 Aug 20 21:58 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 stulluk stulluk 3771 Aug 20 21:58 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 stulluk stulluk  807 Aug 20 21:58 .profile
drwx------ 2 stulluk stulluk 4096 Aug 18 10:46 .ssh/
stulluk@99c477bbf0ba:~$ touch file
stulluk@99c477bbf0ba:~$ exit
exit
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $  docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.5
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.6
 Git commit:        ced0996
 Built:             Fri Jul 21 20:35:18 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.5
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.6
  Git commit:       a61e2b4
  Built:            Fri Jul 21 20:35:18 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.22
  GitCommit:        8165feabfdfe38c65b599c4993d227328c231fca
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.8
  GitCommit:        v1.1.8-0-g82f18fe
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
stulluk ~/docker-nonroot-test (main) $
```

I tried this with different kernels, and it seems this is unrelated to host kernel.